# How do I change what way a block is facing when using //set [Minecraft 1.16.3 WorldEdit]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-worldedit

I have always used either WorldEdit on 1.8.9 or a less well known version of WorldEdit where I could just do `//set 17:2` but when I try to do `//set dark_oak_log:2` It says `Invalid value for ('dark_oak_log:2' was not recognized) acceptable values are any pattern`

I don't have much experience with newer versions of WorldEdit.

I am on Minecraft Version 1.16.3. and WorldEdit version 7.2.0.

Comment: In 1.13+ facing is an NBT tag not a data value, damage values don’t exist in 1.13+

Comment: @Penguin A block state, not an NBT tag.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. What I needed to do is, do `polished_blackstone_brick_stairs[facing=west]`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem, but with wanting the barrel to be facing upwards. To do this, you can use the `[facing=up]` or `[facing=down]` command.

However there is a special case, e.g. oak logs. These require `[axis=x]` or `[axis=y]` or `[axis=z]` to show which direction you want it to face. For example setting the `axis` to `y` sets it to face vertically. `z` and `x` represent the two axes in the 2-dimensional area.